# ¿Cómo hacer un buzón de mensajes con PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacíon web de una tienda on-line, hay un módulo del cliente donde va a tener un buzón de mensajes.
Como estoy usando la librería de PHPMailer me está surgiendo una duda grandísima,
para el cliente, tengo este código:

```
<?php
 //enviar email al administrador
function enviarAdjunto($email, $nombreUsuario, $asunto, $cuerpo){
require 'php/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //mostrar los errores
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Modificar
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Modificar
$mail->Port = 587; // Modificar
$mail->Username = 'administrador@gmail.com'; // Modificar
$mail->Password = 'Lalalalala_12656532'; // Modificar

$mail->setFrom('administrador@gmail.com'); // Modificar REMITENTE
$mail->addAddress($email, $nombreUsuario); // DESTINATARIO

$mail->Subject = $asunto;
$mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

//ENVIO DEL EMAIL ...
if($mail->send() ) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

La gran duda es, ¿para mi cliente tiene que configurar su correo electrónico (gmail, outlook, hotmail) para que pueda enviar mensajes desde la aplicación?

Yo como administrador tuve que configurar mi correo de gmail para poder enviar correos a mis clientes, por eso pregunto que si mi cliente también tiene que configurar su correo.
¿Alguien puede aclarar mis dudas?

Comment: ¿A quien tiene o puede enviar correos tu cliente?

Comment: El asunto es que el cliente tiene que enviar mensajes al administrador

Comment: En mi opinión no tiene por que configurar ningún correo. Tu puedes construir el cuerpo del mensaje como quieras, si necesitas datos de una persona que está registrada, que manda un mensaje, añádelos al cuerpo del correo, después contestas de igual forma, con el cuerpo que desees o desde el gestor de correos que desees. La aplicación simplemente se encarga de enviar los mensajes a un destinatario concreto, nada más.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, estoy entendiendo

Comment: Y una opción también es añadir el email del remitente en `$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@email.com', 'Reply to name');`, aunque en `addFrom` esté especificado el email de la aplicación que estás usando. Hay muchas formas de plantearlo para cubrir casi cualquier necesidad que tengas.

Comment: Oye, ya intenté de la manera en como me explicaste, pero cuando mi cliente envía el correo el mensaje llega pero con los datos del administrador. El código es el mismo que estoy usando.

Comment: ¿Cuáles serían los cambios en el código?